# Why does Chrome take requests INSIDE an iframe to be cross-site requests?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, samesite

Here is the situation:

My webapp maintains session via the usual session cookie. My webapp is displayed inside an iframe in another site. My app, which is within the iframe, sends various ajax requests. Chrome blocks the session cookie because it considers these requests to be cross-site. Then my server doesn't see the session cookie, so answers with a 401.

This forces me to relax the SameSite attribute and set it to `None` for the session cookie, **thereby opening the door to cross site attacks!** Anyone could post anything to my site and the session cookie would be sent!

My site needs to be accessed from both in and out of an iframe, in case you are wondering, that can't be changed.

I can't believe that Google would make what seems like a huge conceptual mistake. 
Is there any good reason why this is like this? Is there any good solution?

Another disonance that I'm experiencing, and which also seems like a big conceptual mistake, is that they will not send cross-site requests if the cookie is not marked as secure (HTTPS only). It messes with development where I use HTTP and production where I use HTTPS. I also don't understand why they mix the meaning of `SameSite` into the meaning of `Secure`? For me this is they taking decisions for developers, and I can't seem to find a positive reason, so please enlighten me :)